# Gibbs sampling step for variables that have a complex offline prior in an MCMC hybrid

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

I have a question about how to use an offline function as a prior when performing a Gibbs/hybrid  analysis.

Let's say I have data $y$ and some parameters which I'll simplify to $\theta_1, \theta_2$. Next, let's say I am working on a Gibbs sampler step $t$ for $\theta_1^{(t)}$ (which I'll simply call $\theta_1$) and the other parameter $\theta_2^{(t-1)}$ is fixed. The conditional posterior of $\theta_1$ is being evaluated and if it had an independent prior, I would have:

$$
p(\theta_1 | y, \theta_2^{(t-1)}) \propto p(y | \theta_1, \theta_2^{(t-1)})p(\theta_1)
$$
In an MCMC hybrid, I would try to make use of the proportionality using a Metropolis-Hastings step. I have found many examples.

In my case, the thing that makes this harder is that instead of independent priors I want to use a function that will describe the "reasonableness" of any pair $f(\theta_1, \theta_2)$. The function is complicated, but I can evaluate it and it decreases rapidly outside a limited region.

My question is, can I make use of this reasonableness function in the hybrid context? I haven't seen examples. The idea I had was to fix $\theta_2$ when evaluating $f$:

$$
p(\theta_1 | y,\theta_2^{(t-1)}) \propto p(y | \theta_1, \theta_2 ^{(t-1)})f(\theta_1, \theta_2^{(t-1)})
$$

and then I would use an MH step for the update. Assuming $f$ is bounded and decays as I claimed, is this idea sound?

Comment: Just to clarify: is the aim to sampler from $f ( \theta_1, \theta_2 ) \cdot p ( y | \theta_1, \theta_2 )$? i.e. from the algorithmic side, $f$ may as well be a prior, just one which happens to encode dependence between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Yes, since I think what you have written is the full posterior density of the data and parameters.